# Azure Blob Storage - Uploading Http/StreamContent to a CloudBlockBlob from WebApi Controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage

I am sending a PDF file to my WebAPI Controller via a POST request using Angular as such:

```
  $scope.upload = Upload.upload({
        url: "../api/Locker/Upload", // webapi url
        method: "POST",
        file: controllerFile,
  })
```

which in my POST method on my controller I get the StreamContent of that file as follows:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
        if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<CustomMultipartFormDataProvider>(new CustomMultipartFormDataProvider());

        string fileName = result.FileData[0].Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
        var fileData = result.Contents[0]; 

 }
```

It is saying that results.Contents[0] is of type HttpContent but in the Immediate window when I type fileData it says it is of StreamContent type.

I am trying to upload to Azure Blob Storage this fileData so that I can then retrieve it using a GET request later on, but am having trouble doing so.

```
    //in post method
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConnectionString);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainer);
    await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    string blobId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    UploadToBlob(container, blobId, fileData);
```

and method where I am stuck:

```
  private async void UploadToBlob(CloudBlobContainer container, string blobId, HttpContent fileData)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob block = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobId);
        block.UploadFromStream(fileData);
    }
```

error on block.UploadFromStream because fileData is not a Stream of course.

What can I do if I am expecting a HTTP Response with content being of type: arraybuffer so that I can expose the file in my web application such as:

```
  //angular get request
 .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);

        var fileBack = new Blob([(data)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileBack);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about block.UploadFromStream(await fileData.ReadAsStreamAsync())?